# std::vector is missing in eclipse on the windows paltform

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, std

I am using eclipse 3.7.2 and uses MinGW gcc 4.6.1 as my compiler.
every thing works ok with , , 
and also I included  header to my source file but I can't define any vector type in the source file. when I comment out error line in the following image every thing went ok and compiles nice. I cant figure out the problem.

Comment: Try vector<string> arr; or vector<int> arr; or vector<float> arr;  You must instantiate a template with a type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You miss the template argument as the error message suggests:

```
vector<int> arr;
```

replace int with the type you want to store

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the `template type` of your vector.

Like `vector<int> arr;`

Take a look at this:

> In their implementation in the C++ Standard Template Library vectors take two template parameters:
>   template < class T, class Allocator = allocator > class vector;
>   Where the template parameters have the following meanings:
>
> T: Type of the elements.
>
> Allocator: Type of the allocator object used to define the storage allocation model.
>       By default, the allocator class template for type T is used, 
>       which defines the simplest memory allocation model and is value-independent.

Answer (score 1):

`vector` is a template type in C++, you need to specify its template parameters (a vector of what?) like `vector<int>`